# Smoothing a map between curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory

In the paper *Families of Rationally Connected Varieties*, the authors consider a map $X\rightarrow B$, where $X$ is obtained by taking disjoint copies of $B$ mapping isomorphically to $B$ and identifying pairs of points on different components of $X$ lying over the same point of $B$.

The paper says that it is easy to check that the morphism can be smoothed. What theorems need to be cited to make this work? In particular, I think I see how to get a formal family of deformations, but how do we get a family over some finite type scheme $S$?

Comment: First of all, there is a more precise formulation of this step in the article with de Jong.  Secondly, just choose a sufficiently ample invertible sheaf on the domain curve, say $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$, with associated projective embedding $C\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$.  Then let $C\to B\times \mathbb{P}^n$ be the diagonal embedding.  Deformations of $C$ as a curve with a morphism to $B$ lift to deformations of $C$ as a closed subscheme of $B\times \mathbb{P}^n$.  So the Hilbert scheme gives $S$.